# How can I check if Any value isEmpty?

Tags: scala, structural-typing

I have the following trait and class (actually this is a simplification, the real code is written in Java and is outside of my control):

```
trait BusinessTermValue {
  def getValue: Any
}

class BusinessTermValueImpl(override val getValue: Any) extends BusinessTermValue
```

Now I'm trying to improve my API without touching the original code (Pimp My Library pattern):

```
package object businessterms {

  implicit final class BusinessTermValueSupport(val btv: BusinessTermValue) extends AnyVal {

    def isDefined(): Boolean = btv != null && btv.value != null

    def isEmpty(): Boolean = isDefined() && (btv.value match {
      case s: String => s.isEmpty
      case l: Traversable[_] => l.isEmpty
      case c: java.util.Collection[_] => c.isEmpty
      case _ => false
    })

    def getAs[T](): T = btv.value.asInstanceOf[T]

  }

  object BusinessTerm {
    def apply(value: Any): BusinessTermValue = new BusinessTermValueImpl(value)
  }

}
```

It works quite well:

```
println(BusinessTerm("A String").isEmpty) // false
println(BusinessTerm(1).isEmpty) // false, Int can't be empty
println(BusinessTerm(new Integer(1)).isEmpty) // false, Integer can't be empty
println(BusinessTerm(List(1, 2, 3)).isEmpty) // false
println(BusinessTerm(List(1, 2, 3).asJava).isEmpty) // false
println(BusinessTerm("").isEmpty) // true
println(BusinessTerm(List()).isEmpty) // true
println(BusinessTerm(Seq()).isEmpty) // true
println(BusinessTerm(Map()).isEmpty) // true
println(BusinessTerm(List().asJava).isEmpty) // true
```

Still the pattern matching in `isEmpty` is cumbersome. Ideally I would like to use structural types and make sure that any type that implements `isEmpty` works with my API.

Unfortunately the code below doesn't work. The variable `e` matches any type, even when `value` does not define `isEmpty`:

```
def isEmpty(): Boolean = isDefined() && (btv.value match {
  case e: { def isEmpty(): Boolean } => e.isEmpty
  case _ => false
})
```

Is there a way to delegate `isEmpty` only when the underlying `value` implements it?

Comment: One way I can think of to solve this problem is using reflection to check for the existence of the `isEmpty` method on the type of `btv.value`. Reflection is of course not compile time safety, but for this particular usage, it might be ok :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was the one suggesting the Try version

```
def isEmpty(): Boolean = isDefined && (btv.value match {
  case e: { def isEmpty(): Boolean } => Try(e.isEmpty).getOrElse(false)
  case _ => false
})
```

I also noted that catching exceptions is expensive but I believe that this case would be the least common as in principle you would be using this construct when you expect to have an isEmpty method. So I think the trade-off may pay and would consider this a case of defensive coding.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Java class that is not under your control returns `Any`/`Object`, you don't have any compile-time type safety anyway, so you don't lose anything by using reflection directly.

Here is an `isEmpty` implementation that works with Java-reflection. It's implemented as a function, but it should be trivial to change it into a method of your wrapper class:

```
def isEmpty(a: Any): Boolean = {
  try {
    a.getClass.getMethod("isEmpty").invoke(a).asInstanceOf[Boolean]
  } catch {
    case e: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException => false
  }
}
```

Here are a few examples:

```
println(isEmpty("hello"))
println(isEmpty(""))
println(isEmpty(List(1,2,3)))
println(isEmpty(Nil))
println(isEmpty(0 to 10))
println(isEmpty(42 until 42))
println(isEmpty(Some(42)))
println(isEmpty(None))
println(isEmpty((x: Int) => x * x))
```

It prints `false`/`true` in an alternating manner. It does not throw any nasty exceptions if it gets an object that has no `isEmpty` method, as the last example demonstrates.

---

**EDIT**

A more robust version would be this:

```
def isEmpty(a: Any): Boolean = {
  try {
    val m = a.getClass.getMethod("isEmpty")
    if (m.getParameterCount == 0) {
      m.invoke(a).asInstanceOf[Boolean]
    } else {
      false
    }
  } catch {
    case e: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException => false
    case e: java.lang.ClassCastException => false
  }
}
```

It guards against the cases that `isEmpty` is not nullary, and that it doesn't return a `Boolean`. However, it's still not "perfect", because it could happen that the method `isEmpty` is overloaded. Maybe `org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect` could come in handy.

Comment: You should also catch `java.lang.ClassCastException` in case the class has a method `isEmpty` that does not return a Boolean. (or catch `Exception`)

Comment: @retrospectacus Added a slightly more robust version.

Comment: Thanks for your input Andrey and @retrospectacus. A friend of mine created a "compressed" version of the reflect / swallow exception approach `case e: { def isEmpty(): Boolean } => Try(e.isEmpty).getOrElse(false)`. It works but still feel a little bit dirty.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly it's a pity that this friend of yours has not posted it as an answer, I would definitely upvote that :D Didn't know that such duck-typing tricks work in Scala! Nice.

Comment: Hey Andrey... Sort off. I mean, as per the last example the `e` case will match everything and if `isEmpty` is not defined it will throw a runtime exception. Still, if you assume that the user will not call `isEmpty` with an unsupported type very often it will do. Still trying to decide if its worth it (the original version may still be better).